# Change name or variable of TextView everytime it goes through a loop - Android

Tags: android, loops, android-asynctask, textview

How can I change the name of a textView every time it goes through a while loop? An example would be this

```
    while( i < 10){

    textView[i].setText("example");
    i++;
    }
```

I have tried this and it says I can not put an array onto a textView so how can I accomplish this? Another problem is the textView is inside of a asynctask class. So I can not create a new textView inside of the class it has to be created out side of the class, so its like this,

```
     TextView commentView = new TextView;
     class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            } 
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            } 
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);  
                    return json2;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                                 commentView[i].setText(json2.getArray(i));
            }
        }
```

This is bassically what my code is, I am trying to get the idea across without me putting all my random code into it.

Comment: if you wanted to create an array of TextView's you would have to declare commentView as a TextView[] and then assign or create TextViews to fill it

Comment: Are you trying to create 5 different `TextView`s or just change the text 5 times? Also, is this class an inner class of your `Activity` or a separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `commentView` is of type `TextView` and it is not of type `Array` and you have to initialize the `TextView` as below:

```
 TextView commentView = new TextView(this);
```

and in `onPostExecute()` assign a random value as below:

```
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        commentView.setText(json2.getArray(i));
     }
    }
```

or if you want the random JSON text to multiple textViews do it as below:

```
   TextView[] commentView = new TextView[TextViewCount];
   @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    for(int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++) {
        commentView[i] = new TextView(this);
    }
 } 
   @Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        commentView[i].setText(json2.getArray(i));

    }
  }
```

Comment: What if instead of a textView it was creating a new linearLayout every time, how could I then set a random value to the LinearLayout without setting a text to the LinearLayout?

Comment: What does TEXTVIEWCOUNT equal?

Comment: Count of Objects in your JSON array

Comment: I have tried this and I can not create new TextViews inside of the onPreExecute() function.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array of commentViews, if you have multiple of them.

You can define the array outside of the AsyncTask, but initialize them within, or assign them, if you have them defined in an XML.

```
    TextView[] commentView = new TextView[textViewCount];

    class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        for(int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++) {
            commentView[i] = new TextView(this);
        }
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    } 

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
    //do your work here

        JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);

        return json2;



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            commentView[i].setText(json2.getArray(i));

        }


    }
}
```